# Parse json content in azure stream analytics

Tags: json, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

My SQL skills are very limited. Please help.

Modbus module on the Azure IoT edge returns JSON content to Stream Analytics job in this format (from downloaded sample data) -

```
[
  {
    "PublishTimestamp": "2021-07-28 19:28:15",
    "Content": [
      {
        "HwId": "XY-MOD2-1",
        "Data": [
          {
            "CorrelationId": "DefaultCorrelationId",
            "SourceTimestamp": "2021-07-28 19:28:15",
            "Values": [
              {
                "DisplayName": "Temperature",
                "Address": "30002",
                "Value": "210"
              },
              {
                "DisplayName": "Temperature",
                "Address": "30003",
                "Value": "538"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2021-07-28T20:26:23.9127084Z",
    "PartitionId": 0,
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2021-07-28T19:28:15.9460000Z",
    "IoTHub": {
      "MessageId": null,
      "CorrelationId": null,
      "ConnectionDeviceId": "rp4linuxedge1",
      "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637630846187016425",
      "EnqueuedTime": "2021-07-28T19:28:15.9550000Z",
      "StreamId": null
    }
  },
```

I am unable to figure out what SQL syntax should I use to get this as output -

| SourceTimestamp | Address | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Time1 | 30002 | 210 |
| Time1 | 30003 | 538 |
| Time2 | 30002 | 215 |
| Time2 | 30003 | 540 |

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The array within the JSON object can be accessed using this block of codes -

```
select 
    cast(dataArr.ArrayValue.SourceTimestamp as datetime) as SourceTimestamp, 
    cast(valuesArr.ArrayValue.Address as bigint) as Address, 
    cast(valuesArr.ArrayValue.Value as float) as Value

into powerbioutput
from iotinput i
cross apply GetArrayElements(i.Content) as contentArr
cross apply GetArrayElements(contentArr.ArrayValue.Data) as dataArr
cross apply GetArrayElements(dataArr.ArrayValue.[Values]) as valuesArr
```